# If $E|X|<+\infty$ then $\int_{\left(|X|>n\right)}X \;dP\to 0$

Tags: probability-theory

Let X be a random variable defined on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathbf{F},P )$. If $E|X|<+\infty$, How do I prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\left(|X|>n\right)} X \ dP=0 \,?$$

Comment: Please make the title more informative (and less subjective).

Comment: @Chris, this is **NOT** what is asked...

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Rolling back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X_n=|X|\cdot[|X|\geqslant n]$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} X_n=0$ almost surely, you ask why $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathrm E(X_n)=\mathrm E\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_n\right)$.

**Hint:** Use Lebesgue's [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) with the domination condition $|X_n|\leqslant|X|$.

Answer (score 5):

Put $A_k:=\left\{\omega\in\Omega,k\leq |X(\omega)|<k+1\right\}$. We have for all $k\geq 0$:
$$kP(A_k)\leq \int_{k\leq X<k+1}|X|dP\leq (k+1)P(A_k)$$
hence 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}kP(A_k)\leq E|X|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(k+1)P(A_k).$$
Since $E|X|$ is finite, the series $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}kP(A_k)$ is convergent and since $(k+1)P(A_k)\sim kP(A_k)$, the series $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(k+1)P(A_k)$ is also convergent. Now, we have 
$$\int_{|X|\geq n}|X|dP=\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}\int_{A_k}|X|dP\leq \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}(k+1)P(A_k),$$ 
which is the remainder of a convergent series.