# Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^p P(X>x)=0$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X$ be a positive random variable on the $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$. Show that if $X\in L_p$ for $1<p<\infty$.
>   Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^p P(X>x)=0$

Using Chebyshev inequality:

$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^p P(X>x)\leqslant\lim_{x\to\infty} x^p\frac{1}{x^p} \int_{X>x}|X|^p dP=\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{X>x}|X|^p dP $

Is it true $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{X>x}|X|^p dP=0 $?

**Questions:**

Is my reasoning right? How do I prove  $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{X>x}|X|^p dP=0 $?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using Markov's inequality, not Chebyshev.

Comment: @user10354138 every this kind of inequality can be proved using Chebyshev inequality, hence we usually call all of them by the common name of THE Chebyshev inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\int_{X>x} |X|^p \ d P \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. This is just a consequence of the fact that the integral $\int |X|^p \ dP$ is finite. Another way to think of this is that $\int_{0 \leq X <x}|X|^p \ dP \to \int|X|^p \ dP$ as $x \to \infty$. More details can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76748/if-ex-infty-then-int-leftxn-rightx-dp-to-0?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{X>x} |X|^{p}\, dP=\int I_{X>x} |X|^{p}\, dP \to 0$ by DCT since the integrand tends to $0$ at every point and $|X|^{p}$ is a dominating integrable function.